# MRTG Total Throughput in Week/Month

Tags: monitoring, mrtg

We have been running MRTG for quite some time to keep an eye on our router usage at remote offices. We now have a need to see roughly how much data (pref in GB) has been transferred over the link.

Can I get MRTG to tell me this info, or am i going to have to use something else?

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MRTS](http://apt-get.dk/mrts/) for this task, it gathers information from RRD Files (these are generated by MRTG) and displays statistics of traffic in/out/total over desired timeperiods.
MRTS is just a php script, so no need to install it per se.

It's also open-source, so you can add functionality or alter its behaviour.

Comment: Looks promising, ill give it a go tomorow

Answer (score 0):

You definetly can use MRTG to gather/display this information.
It a common practice to separate up and down data volumes.

Some basic routers don't have this information, but every other have it into their SNMP MIB (I think you use SNMP with MRTG, not sure. Else just use whatever method you want, as long as you get the volume transfered).

Answer (score 0):

As with all things MRTG, its just a matter of finding/using the right OID or modifying the target to suit what you need. MRTG essentially collects numbers and graphs them. By default it collects the numbers via snmp, or you can write your own scripts (sh, bash, perl, whatever) to output the numbers that MRTG graphs for you.

If you want a cumulative graph or just to display the same data in GB per second all you need to do is add a new target or modify the one you have (your original post is not clear to me in that way).

For example if you wanted to keep the one traffic graph but have it show in GB per second also, copy the target for that graph, and then apply the appropriate math to the target. That number is pretty big so you may be thinking something different.

Depending on what you are actually looking for you might use the gauge option for the target. If you are looking for 95 percentile there are lots of hits on Google for that.